# Which virtue did each Heartiel stand for?

Tags: pretty-cure

During the Max Heart season of Pretty Cure, the characters are hunting down the 12 Heartiels.  These little fairies represent the virtues of

> the Queen of Light.

While some of them are named after their virtue (Seekun seeks knowledge, Harmonin = Harmony), others have names that have nothing to do with a virtue (Horpun).

**Could someone explain what their virtues are?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Precure wikia](http://prettycure.wikia.com/wiki/Heartiels), the list of Heartiels and Virtues are:

```
╔══════════════════╦══════════════╦════════════════╗
║       Name       ║    Virtue    ║     Symbol     ║
╠══════════════════╬══════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Eternalun        ║ Eternal      ║ Pocket Watch   ║
║ Lovelun (rabrun) ║ Love         ║ Ring           ║
║ Prosen           ║ Prosperity   ║ Pear           ║
║ Pyuan            ║ Purity       ║ Snowflake      ║
║ Inteligen        ║ Intelligence ║ Book           ║
║ Wishun           ║ Wish         ║ Mirror         ║
║ Braven           ║ Bravery      ║ Crown          ║
║ Harmonin         ║ Harmony      ║ Treasure Chest ║
║ Hapinen          ║ Happiness    ║ Bell           ║
║ Horpun           ║ Positivity   ║ Key            ║
║ Pation           ║ Passion      ║ Torch          ║
║ Seekun           ║ Seek         ║ Telescope      ║
╚══════════════════╩══════════════╩════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept this. :)